# ATI Driver installer screen missing nearly all text, how do I resolve this?

Tags: ati, text, button

I am using 64-Bit Ubuntu 12.10 On a Dell 7520, intel core i5 3210, ati 7730m, 4gb DDR3

I downloaded ATI catalyst software driver for linux (amd-driver-installer-catalyst-12.10-x86.x86_64.run), but when i run it using `sudo ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-12.10-x86.x86_64.run` the application window is visible but no text is seen:

[image: driver installer-missing text 1]
[image: driver installer-missing text 2]

I want to know weather extra fonts are needed or something else. Please tell me how.

Thank You.

Comment: Could be related to switchable graphics maybe.  That dell model has intel/ati switchable.  If intel is active maybe a bug in the driver installer.

Comment: I ran it again on terminal screen(ctrl+alt+F1). It ran fine then, but after installation when i restarted, logged in, i could see nothing on screen rather than just wallpaper. I had to use terminal screen(ctrl+alt+F1) to reboot

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue. After beating my head over it for a long time, I discovered the cause: locale. I assume you have locale set to something other than en_US. Try this as root (for any amd-catalyst version):

LANG="en_US" /bin/bash ./amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.run

from the directory in which the driver is. Fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanx.. this saved my day