# AMD driver installer without text

Tags: drivers, ati, software-installation, 14.04

I am trying to install `AMD` drivers on my `Dell inspiron 15R`. I downloaded beta drivers from [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64). I extracted the the downloaded zip file. Then i executed `amd-driver-installer-14.10-x86.x86_64.run`. Now the installer comes up, but it doesn't show any text in it. [image: install]

Comment: Why you don't use repos?

Comment: same issue latest stable drivers downloaded from amd website. any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/237203/ati-driver-installer-screen-missing-nearly-all-text-how-do-i-resolve-this

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this using this

Language packs are missing from your system, Install and apply language packs before continuing with the installation of the AMD Catalyst driver. To install and apply the language packs, go to System Settings -> Language Support, will install default packages, Tick System Wide

Also be sure to check /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for any missing prerequsite packages this is not mentioned in driver version 14.10 but the BETA 14.20 does mention this information.